# Drupal9: Saving form as node in SQL (custom module example)

Tags: sql, forms, drupal, drupal-modules

i develop a custom module with forms to save data in SQL-Datebase. I want to use for that the node-structure.

Normal SQL-savings for example table works but not for the node-tables.
Any idea what is going wrong?

This ist my Code for saving, which works in non-node-tables:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { $connection = \Drupal::service('database');
$result = $connection->insert('node.node__body')
  ->fields(['body_value'])
  ->values([
    'body_value' => 'text for body',
    ])
  ->execute();

$form_state->setRedirect('modulname.form'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Entity API in Drupal to manipulate or create a node.

In your case,

```php
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create(
      [
        'type'  => 'page',
        'title' => 'New Basic Page',
        'body'  => 'text for body'
      ]
    );
```

Here, `type` is the content type machine name. Don't forget to update with your own. Also you probably want to inject the entity_type.manager service and use in the code.

Get more info here: [Working with entities in Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/working-with-the-entity-api)